# Using MSAL with authentication context in C# WPF desktop app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We would like to use the authentication context feature of Azure AD (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/conditional-access-authentication-context-now-in-public-preview/ba-p/1942484) in our desktop app to trigger conditional access when certain parts of our app are used.

The documentation provides samples of a web api and web app (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-ca-auth-context-app/blob/main/README.md https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-ca-auth-context/blob/main/README.md), but there is no documentation on how to secure parts of a desktop app with this feature.

In the desktop app (c# WPF 4.8) we use the MSAL library (4.35.1), also there we do not find any options / features to use the authentication context inside of the app.

Is it possible or the intention to be able to use authentication context inside a desktop app, or is it targeted at a web scenario?

Comment: Tom Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement authentication on any platforms. There are no platforms limitations.

***Get Token:***

For desktp application steps are almost same. You can get token this way:

```
             authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithAccount(firstAccount)
                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle) // optional, used to center the browser on the window
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
```

***Access Resource with Token:***

```
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
```

You can download the sample application from [here in official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop#set-up-your-project)

Let me know if you require any further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know how to request authentication tokens for scopes which we can use for backend calls. My question here is more specific, can we use authentication context to trigger conditional access (in practice MFA) when a user uses specific parts in the desktop application.

Comment: So whats your additional concern?

Comment: My concern is : Can we trigger conditional access (MFA) in a desktop application when a user accesses certain parts of an application (possibly with authenication context, perhaps there is another way)

Comment: Yes you can but for your information condition access(MFA) you have to enable it on azure not matter which platform you using. You could check [here in official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks)